# Portfolio-modal with 17px of padding-left automatically

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I took the code of this template: [Template Here](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/agency/)

I'm using a `portfolio-modal` with bootstrap and it is showing the following error:

When I open, the modal appears with +`padding-left:17px` automaticaly. I opened the console and it show:

```
 element.style {
 display: block;
 padding-left: 17px;
 }
```

[image: Modal with <code>padding-left:17px;</code>]

However, this code don't exists. I don't know how, but it is being added automatically.

Has anyone experienced this problem?
Does anyone know how to solve this bug/conflict?

```js
.img-centered {
    margin:0 auto
}


#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .portfolio-hover {
    background:#f05f40;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    opacity:0;
    transition:all ease .5s;
    -webkit-transition:all ease .5s;
    -moz-transition:all ease .5s
}
#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .portfolio-hover:hover {
    opacity:1
}
#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .portfolio-hover .portfolio-hover-content {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-12px;
    color:#fff
}
#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .portfolio-hover .portfolio-hover-content i {
    margin-top:-12px
}
#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .portfolio-hover .portfolio-hover-content h3, #portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .portfolio-hover .portfolio-hover-content h4 {
    margin:0
}
#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-caption {
    max-width:400px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    padding:25px
}
#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-caption h4 {
    text-transform:none;
    margin:0
}
#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-caption p {
    font-family:"Droid Serif", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-style:italic;
    font-size:16px;
    margin:0
}

.portfolio-modal .modal-content {
    border-radius:0;
    background-clip:border-box;
    -webkit-box-shadow:none;
    box-shadow:none;
    border:0;
    min-height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding:100px 0;
    text-align:center;
}
.portfolio-modal .modal-content h2 {
    margin-bottom:15px;
    font-size:3em
}
.portfolio-modal .modal-content p {
    margin-bottom:30px
}
.portfolio-modal .modal-content p.item-intro {
    margin:20px 0 30px;
    font-family:"Droid Serif", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-style:italic;
    font-size:16px
}
.portfolio-modal .modal-content ul.list-inline {
    margin-bottom:30px;
    margin-top:0
}
.portfolio-modal .modal-content img {
    margin-bottom:30px
}
.portfolio-modal .close-modal {
    position:absolute;
    width:75px;
    height:75px;
    background-color:transparent;
    bottom:25px;
    right:25px;
    cursor:pointer
}
.portfolio-modal .close-modal:hover {
    opacity:.3
}
.portfolio-modal .close-modal .lr {
    height:75px;
    width:1px;
    margin-left:35px;
    background-color:#222;
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    z-index:1051
}
.portfolio-modal .close-modal .lr .rl {
    height:75px;
    width:1px;
    background-color:#222;
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    z-index:1052
}
.portfolio-modal .modal-backdrop {
    opacity:0;
    display:none
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<section class="no-padding" id="portfolio">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row no-gutter">
               
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                     <a href="#portfolioModal1" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">                      
                       <div class="portfolio-hover">
                            <div class="portfolio-hover-content">                            
                                <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div> 

                        <img src="http://veja.abril.com.br/blog/radar-on-line/files/2015/04/modal.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""> 
                      </a>     
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>



<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
                <div class="lr">
                    <div class="rl">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            
                            <h2>Project Name</h2>
                            <p class="item-intro text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
                            <img class="img-responsive img-centered" src="img/portfolio/roundicons-free.png" alt="">
                          
                            <p>Use this area to describe your project. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est blanditiis dolorem culpa incidunt minus dignissimos deserunt repellat aperiam quasi sunt officia expedita beatae cupiditate, maiores repudiandae, nostrum, Use this area to describe your project. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est blanditiis dolorem culpa incidunt minus dignissimos deserunt repellat aperiam quasi sunt officia expedita beatae cupiditate, maiores repudiandae, nostrum,Use this area to describe your project. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est blanditiis dolorem culpa incidunt minus dignissimos deserunt repellat aperiam quasi sunt officia expedita beatae cupiditate, maiores repudiandae, nostrum,Use this area to describe your project. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est blanditiis dolorem culpa incidunt minus dignissimos deserunt repellat aperiam quasi sunt officia expedita beatae cupiditate, maiores repudiandae, nostrum,Use this area to describe your project. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisanditiis dolorem culpa incidunt minus dignissimos deserunt repellat aperiam quasi sunt officia expedita beatae cupiditate, maiores repudiandae, nostrum,Use this area to describe your project. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est blanditiis dolorem culpa incidunt minus dignissimos deserunt repellat aperiam quasi sunt officia expedita beatae cupiditate, maiores repudiandae, nostrum,Use this area to describe your project. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est blanditiis dolorem culpa incidunt minus dignissimos deserunt repellat aperiam quasi sunt officia exsit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est blanditiis dolorem culpa incidunt minus dignissimos deserunt repellat aperiam quasi sunt officia expedita beatae cupiditate, maiores repudiandae, nostrum,Use this area to describe your project. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est blanditiis dolorem culpa incidunt minus dignissimos deserunt repellat aperiam quasi sunt officia expedita beatae cupiditate, maiores repu. Use this area to describe your project. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est blanditiis dolorem culpa incidunt minus dignissimos deserunt repellat aperiam quasi sunt officia expedita beatae cupiditate, maiores repudiandae, nostrum, Use this area to describe your project. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est blanditiis dolorem culpa incidunt minus dignissimos deserunt repellat aperiam quasi sunt officia expedita beatae cupiditate, maiores repudiandae, nostrum,Use this area to describe your project. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est blanditiis dolorem culpa incidunt minus dignissimos deserunt repellat aperiam quasi sunt officia expedita beatae cupiditate, maiores repudiandae, nostrum,Use this area to describe your project. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est blanditiis dolorem culpa incidunt minus dignissimos deserunt repellat aperiam quasi sunt officia expedita beatae cupiditate, maiores repudiandae, nostrum,Use this area to describe your project. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisanditiis dolorem culpa incidunt minus dignissimos deserunt repellat aperiam quasi sunt officia expedita beatae cupiditate, maiores repudiandae, nostrum,Use this area to describe your project. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est blanditiis dolorem culpa incidunt minus dignissimos deserunt repellat aperiam quasi sunt officia expedita beatae cupiditate, maiores repudiandae, nostrum,Use this area to describe your project. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est blanditiis dolorem culpa incidunt minus dignissimos deserunt repellat aperiam quasi sunt officia exsit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est blanditiis dolorem culpa incidunt minus dignissimos deserunt repellat aperiam quasi sunt officia expedita beatae cupiditate, maiores repudiandae, nostrum,Use this area to describe your project. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est blanditiis dolorem culpa incidunt minus dignissimos deserunt repellat aperiam quasi sunt officia expedita beatae cupiditate, maiores repuUse this area to describe your project. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est blanditiis dolorem culpa incidunt minus dignissimos deserunt repellat aperiam quasi sunt officia expedita beatae cupiditate, maiores repudiandae, nostrum, Use this area to describe your project. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est blanditiis dolorem culpa incidunt minus dignissimos deserunt repellat aperiam quasi sunt officia expedita beatae cupiditate, maiores repudiandae, nostrum,Use this area to describe your project. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est blanditiis dolorem culpa incidunt minus dignissimos deserunt repellat aperiam quasi sunt officia expedita beatae cupiditate, maiores repudiandae, nostrum,Use this area to describe your project. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est blanditiis dolorem culpa incidunt minus dignissimos deserunt repellat aperiam quasi sunt officia expedita beatae cupiditate, maiores repudiandae, nostrum,Use this area to describe your project. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisanditiis dolorem culpa incidunt minus dignissimos deserunt repellat aperiam quasi sunt officia expedita beatae cupiditate, maiores repudiandae, nostrum,Use this area to describe your project. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est blanditiis dolorem culpa incidunt minus dignissimos deserunt repellat aperiam quasi sunt officia expedita beatae cupiditate, maiores repudiandae, nostrum,Use this area to describe your project. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est blanditiis dolorem culpa incidunt minus dignissimos deserunt repellat aperiam quasi sunt officia exsit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est blanditiis dolorem culpa incidunt minus dignissimos deserunt repellat aperiam quasi sunt officia expedita beatae cupiditate, maiores repudiandae, nostrum,Use this area to describe your project. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est blanditiis dolorem culpa incidunt minus dignissimos deserunt repellat aperiam quasi sunt officia expedita beatae cupiditate, maiores repu</p>
                          
                          <strong>Want these icons in this portfolio item sample?</strong>You can download 60 of them for free, courtesy of <a href="https://getdpd.com/cart/hoplink/18076?referrer=bvbo4kax5k8ogc">RoundIcons.com</a>, or you can purchase the 1500 icon set <a href="https://getdpd.com/cart/hoplink/18076?referrer=bvbo4kax5k8ogc">here</a>.</p>
                            <ul class="list-inline">
                                <li>Date: July 2014</li>
                                <li>Client: Round Icons</li>
                                <li>Category: Graphic Design</li>
                            </ul>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close Project</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried over-riding the CSS? I've assuming the CSS is coming from one of the bootstrap CSS sources linked ---// element.style {
 display: block;
 padding-left: 0px !important;
 }

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it's being added in javascript.

It will be an inline style on the element, for example

```
<body style="display:block; padding-left:17px;">
```

You should be able to open the dev tools, and ctrl + f / cmd +f to search for 17px and find it.

They are probably adding it to try and offset any jump the page experiences when triggering a popup without a scrollbar added.

an easy way to fix it would be to override the style

```
.offending__element{
    padding-left:0px !important;
}
```

It isn't the best way to fix it, but is the only solution we can provide with what you've supplied.